# How to pass argparse value into function and assign value to dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, arguments, argparse

I have setup a few argparse arguments for my script like so:

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--file", "-i", type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument("--outfile", "-o", type=str, required=False)
parser.add_argument("--tab", "-t", type=str, required=False)
parser.add_argument("--tab_result", "-tr", type=str, required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()


#assign value too variables
infile = args.file
outfilepath = args.outfile
tabs = args.tab
tab_result = args.tab_result
```

I need to pass the variables of each the argparsers above into a function and assign values to a dataframe. I am trying to do this like so:

```
def func1():
    print(infile)
    doc = pd.DataFrame()
    doc['file'] =  infile
    doc['output_table_name'] = outfilepath
    doc['output_table_fields'] = json_normalized['index'] #from another df, works fine
    doc['output_table_datatypes'] = json_normalized['dtypes.name'] #from another df, works fine
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(tabs)
    doc.to_excel(writer,args.documentor_tab)
    writer.save()
    #print(infile)
    #print(outfilename)
    print(doc)

    return doc


print('wrote document')

func1()
```

When I print this dataframe the `infile` and `outpathfile` argparse values dont get assigned to the dataframe columns, however all the rest of the argparse values do.

What I am doing wrong that not all values from argparse are getting assigned to the dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc['file']` references the 'file' column so you can't set it to a string before there are any rows in the dataframe.

If there's only one row in `json_normalized` then you probably want something like this:

```py
def func1(infile, outfilepath, tabs, tabs_result, json_normalized):
    doc = pd.DataFrame(columns=['file', 'output_table_name', 'output_table_fields', 'output_table_datatypes'])

    index = json_normalized['index'][0]
    dtypes_name = json_normalized['dtypes.name'][0]
    doc.loc[0] = [infile, outfilepath, index, dtypes_name]

    ...

    return doc
```

or if you mean to write a whole column of `index` then swap the order:

```py
def func1(infile, outfilepath, tabs, tabs_result, json_normalized):
    doc = pd.DataFrame(columns=['file', 'output_table_name', 'output_table_fields', 'output_table_datatypes'])
    doc['output_table_fields'] = json_normalized['index']
    doc['output_table_datatypes'] = json_normalized['dtypes.name']
    doc['output_table_name'] = outfilepath
    doc['file'] =  infile

    ...

    return doc
```

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` and passing/using variables in a function isn't the issue.  The problem is with how you create the data frame.

Consider this stripped down example:

```
In [255]: doc = pd.DataFrame()                                                  
In [256]: doc['file'] = 'foobar'                                                
In [257]: doc['outfile'] = 'anothername'                                        
In [258]: doc                                                                   
Out[258]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [file, outfile]
Index: []
In [259]: doc['col'] = [1,2,3,4]                                                
In [260]: doc                                                                   
Out[260]: 
  file outfile  col
0  NaN     NaN    1
1  NaN     NaN    2
2  NaN     NaN    3
3  NaN     NaN    4
```

The initial assignments apply to an empty frame, one without any rows.

Assigning the constant values to the columns after creating the rows:

```
In [261]: doc['file'] = 'foobar'                                                
In [262]: doc['outfile'] = 'anothername'                                        
In [263]: doc                                                                   
Out[263]: 
     file      outfile  col
0  foobar  anothername    1
1  foobar  anothername    2
2  foobar  anothername    3
3  foobar  anothername    4
```

Alternatively you could specify the row indices at the start:

```
In [265]: doc = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(5))                                
In [266]: doc                                                                   
Out[266]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
In [267]: doc['file'] = 'foobar'                                                
In [268]: doc['outfile'] = 'anothername'                                        
In [269]: doc                                                                   
Out[269]: 
     file      outfile
0  foobar  anothername
1  foobar  anothername
2  foobar  anothername
3  foobar  anothername
4  foobar  anothername
```